# How to link apache2 to a wordpress docker container?

Tags: wordpress, apache, docker

I have two docker containers (one for mysql and the other for wordpress). it looks like this.

[image]

I would like to link my domain (example.com) to the wordpress container. So far, I came up with this apache config file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin hello@example.com
ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ProxyRequests off
<Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
</Proxy>
<Location />
        ProxyPass http://localhost:4568/
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:4568/
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now, example.com works just fine for the home page but when I try to go to directory (say, http://example.com/product/asdasd) it redirects me to http://localhost/product/asdasd.

I have tried changing localhost in the config file with the domain name but it doesn't work;

```
ProxyPass http://example.com:4568/
ProxyPassReverse http://example.com:4568/
```

Can anyone help me to figure out what is the right config file to do so?

Thnx

Comment: The apache is running on the docker host machine, inside WP the container or elsewhere? Thanks

Comment: Apache is installed in the host machine (VM) outside any docker container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reproduced and just made it work.

You need to add these lines in your `wp-config.php`:

```
define('WP_HOME', 'http://www.example.com/');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://www.example.com/'); `
```

This is the apache config file for my example.com domain:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "http"
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:4568/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:4568/
  <Location />
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

After these changes, WP immediately stopped redirecting to `localhost`:

[image]

If you still face any problems, leave a comment and I'll try to update the post with the other changes that I performed on my apache configs, although those should not be relevant.

Comment: It works. Thank you so much.

I had to remove this line `RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "http"` it shows an error when restarting apache. 

And I added:
`ServerName example.com`
`ServerAlias www.example.com`

Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

To use example.com:4568, you need to expose port 4568 publicly OR
you can set entry in /etc/hosts as
`localhost:4568 example.com`
to keep it private